# Why do all trend vectors in the G1000 on airplanes indicate the status 6 seconds later? Why 6? Why not 5 or 10?

Tags: airspeed, altitude, heading, g1000

Why do all trend vectors in the G1000 on airplanes indicate the status 6 seconds later? Why 6? Why not 5 or 10? The fact that the trend vector shows after 6 seconds allows us to turn 3 degrees per second in standard turns. Anyway, why 6 seconds for speed and altitude? I've also read that on heavy aircraft like the A320, this trend vector shows 10 seconds ahead. Is it related to the plane size?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Speculation: A standard rate turn is 3 degrees/second. Maybe it's convenient to have the trend vector be a multiple of that value

Comment: More speculation: 6 seconds is also a nice fraction of 1 minute (one tenth)  making it easy to extrapolate out to, say, feet per minute.

Comment: The standard turn rate reference mark is located 18 degrees to the right and left of the luber line from the calculation of 6x3=18 degrees. If the trend vector was 5 seconds, it would be 5x3=15 degrees to the right and left. So it's not really about the standard turn speed of 3 degrees/second. @60levelchange

Comment: If we think on a fraction basis, the numbers 5 and 10 are also very good numbers for 60 seconds (1 minute), and they can divide 60 seconds exactly. I don't think the situation is related to that either. @TypeIA

Comment: @pilot162 Most people can mentally multiply/divide by 10 much easier than by 12 or 6, for the obvious reason.

Comment: Adding to the confusion: airspeed trend vector on this system is a *ten* second prediction.  So why is six seconds preferred in one place and not another?